# tasklist.exe "initialization failure"

Tags: windows-xp, 64-bit

One of our Windows XP x64 Pro machines suddenly would not run tasklist.exe (lists processes in cmd line) anymore.  It gives "ERROR: Initialization failure" when run.

Things I've looked into:

-any s/w installs recently? No.

-is tasklist.exe even on the machine? Yes, it's in C:\WINDOWS\system32

-checked path/environment variables? Yes.

-have you tried running it by typing its full path?  Yes, but it still gives the error I mentioned above.

So I'm not too sure what else to look for right now.  Any help is appreciated :)  Thanks.

Comment: Is this the only program that does it? Does procexp from sysinternals work? Can you run a "Clean" 64 big copy from another machine, if you have it available? chkdsk find anything wrong on the drive that may have corrupted it? Antivirus/spybot find anything suspicious on the system?

Comment: Just wanted to add that procexp and taskmanager works.  However, we have an in-house tool that uses tasklist to check for duplicate processes of a certain type and takes appropriate action.  This just happened one day and I don't know why *shrugs*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rebuilding the WMI repository did the trick.  Just posting the solution that I found in case anyone else runs into something similar...

In cmd:

net stop winmgmt

Rename the %windir%\system32\wbem\repository to something else

net start winmgmt

Comment: I did that but (rename repository folder) now i got the error: *"The remote system must be running Windows 2000 or above"* any more idea?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run this command with administrator rights.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I was logged in as admin at the time.